# How likely is a person to develop permanent health issues if he/she is sensitive to and continuously exposed to marijuana fumes?

Tags: cardiology, breathing, lasting-effects-duration, marijuana, smoke-inhalation

I'm a 29 year old male, I live in an apartment, and the tenant above me is smoking a lot of marijuana every day and has been doing so for the last three months**. The fumes are entering my apartment through the HVAC system even when the system is turned off, my windows are open, and two air purifiers are on. I spend virtually every day in my apartment for almost the entire day. I jog 20min/day on the treadmill and my resting heart rate is around 65-75bpm when outside the apartment. While inside the apartment, I continuously experience:

**• Respiratory issues: shortness of breath, lung inflammation, sinus inflammation (flares up sometimes)

•   Heart issues: elevated resting heart rate (80-110 bpm - almost always), heart pain (mild-moderate most of the time), arrhythmia (rarely)

•   Headaches, fatigue, depression (all three: mild-moderate most of the time)**

I have logged my symptoms and they are stronger when the smoking occurs, but persist in a more mild fashion even after the smoking. When the smoking occurs, I also notice several red bars appear on my air purifier air quality indicator. My roommate is not as sensitive to the fumes as I am and only experiences a subset of the above symptoms and those at a much milder level.

While outside of the apartment, all these issues disappear. QVAR has been able to slightly ameliorate only the issue of shortness of breath.

**What are the potential long-term issues if I continue to suffer under these symptoms (as I inhale the fumes) and how likely are these permanent issues to develop?**

** (***Off-topic because not health related***, but I still mention it in case it comes up: I'm 33% through my lease and I cannot get out of it because my roommate refuses to break the lease even if I pay for the termination fees. Further, upon complaining to the smoker, he denies everything (even though the fumes could be smelled from his windows when he used to have them open - before I complained). The management company is afraid to do anything because of potential legal repercussions. The police always arrives about 1h after the smoke has settled. I suffer under the symptoms even when the fumes are very weak and barely noticeable.)

EDIT: I just found the following source:

*Magnus Thorsten Jensen, M.D., cardiologist and researcher, Copenhagen University Hospital Gentofte, Copenhagen, Denmark; Gregg Fonarow, M.D., professor, cardiology, University of California, Los Angeles; April 15, 2013, Heart*

states that those with resting rates of 80+ tend to die 4-5 years earlier.

EDIT2: The following aggregate analysis could explain the symptoms: 
http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/570583_1

I would still welcome more answers of other issues I might have missed.

Comment: Clarification - Is marijuana legal where you live? If not, legal is always a recourse.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm not aware of current marijuana law in my state of Georgia. Even then, it takes the police too long to arrive, and, even if they arrived in time, I think it would be difficult for them to get a warrant.

Comment: On a personal level, your situation is indeed a confounded one, I'm sorry to hear that you have to deal with it. On a site policy level, I'm not sure we can help you. "How likely" is not very answerable even for a single potential outcome counted over a vast majority of "standard" people. But you are asking about any possible outcome, and that for a person who is unusually sensitive and so large epidemiological results are probably not generalizable. Second and related, the question is too close to personal health advice and I don't see how to remove that and still have it applicable (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) to your situation. Third, you are taking a logical leap here. You could be sensitive to something else in the apartment - mold, formaldehyde treated furniture, whatever. You provided a laundry list of symptoms, but there is no certainty it's really a pot connection, especially seeing that marijuana and especially nicotine are generally good for depression, so unlikely to cause it. So I cast a close vote - while your concern is warranted, I don't see how we could help, and I think this is not the type of question this site can do well with.

Comment: @ rumtscho: 1) Thanks for your sympathies. I don't agree with the notion that if the answer to a question seems challenging or speculative, the question should not be asked. 2) TBH I haven't read the rules of the site and I'm sorry if I've broken one of them. 3) From a global perspective, before the marijuana fumes were noticeable, I did not suffer under any of the symptoms. From a local perspective, the more (less) I smell the marijuana fumes, the more (less) severe the symptoms are.The smell of the fumes is heavily correlated with the severity of the air quality indicator of my air purifier.

Comment: (cont.) "especially seeing that marijuana and especially nicotine are generally good for depression, so unlikely to cause it." The National Institute of Drug Abuse writes:"Marijuana use has also been linked to other mental health problems, such as:

    depression " I'm not trying to invalidate the beneficial uses of marijuana - I'm just claiming that I'm sensitive to it.

Comment: Just contact building owner and object. building owners are not allowed to "knowingly" allow criminal behaviour on their premisses

Comment: 1. That HVAC system seems broken. Two airpurifiers unable to eliminate what shouldn't be there in the first place would be the first angle of attack.  Tell the owner to fix that and if necessary or possible seal that HVAC up in the meantime. 2. "every day at my apartment […] the entire day" and "Headaches, fatigue, depression" point to two conclusions: going outside a bit more is general good advice and the symptoms you described might warrant a visit to doctor. -#- agreeing with rumtscho